# Single Use List - Excel

Tags: excel

I'm after a way of preferably using VLookup to return information and once returned, have the source information unavailable for the same lookup.

e.g. If I have a list of names I have not used in seating for an event, I will want a formula which can look up this information WITHOUT entering the same name more than once. I'd rather not do a drop-down option as requires selecting the entry and I want my whole table to be an self-filling database.

I've about 20 nested IF functions going on in one cell so ideally something that could fit in there easily? Ill take anything honestly :P

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please update your question with an example of inputs and expected output.

Comment: You can have a column to store the "taken" flag, update this flag from a macro, and query the next available name where taken=false. If you tried to make the "taken" column a formula as well, that would be a cyclic reference.